# Google Cloud Function works in emulator but errs on deploy to Firebase: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is meant to delete a post with its subcollection of comments. It properly deletes the post in the emulator. However, when I try to deploy the cloud function to Firebase the following error occurs:

> i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function
> recursiveDelete(us-central1)...
> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in
> the user code. Error message:
> Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause:
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
> Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging.
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
> recursiveDelete(us-central1)

As instructed, I checked the error in the log in Google Cloud I found:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1

> at .JSON.parse
> at .parse (
> /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89
> )

This is the function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * Initiate a recursive delete of documents at a given path.
 * @param {string} data.path the document or collection path to delete.
 */

exports.recursiveDelete = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const path = data[0].path;
    console.log(`Running cloud function recursiveDelete on ${path}`);

    await firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: '...', 
        force: true
      });

    return {
      path: path
    };
    
  });
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
  static Future<void> delete(String ref) async {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      throw Exception('Must be logged in');
    }

    await FirebaseFunctions.instance
        .httpsCallable('recursiveDelete')
        .call([{'path': 'posts/$ref'}])
        .then((value) => logger("Post deleted: ${value.data}"))
        .catchError((error) => logger.error("Failed to delete post: $error"));
  }
```

In the emulator, deletion works fine and the output is:

> I/flutter (26907): [Post] [INFO] Post deleted: {path:
> posts/Gk4TeWEgZmm0QUcaqTrk}

So, what's wrong with it?

Full stack-trace:

```
=== Deploying to 'sightings-dev'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/strijdhaftig/sightings/frontend/flutter/sightings/functions (55.13 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function recursiveDelete(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        recursiveDelete(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log
```

Comment: Show the complete stack trace.

Comment: Full stack trace added.

Comment: That is command output. Add the stack trace from the logs.

Comment: The 3 lines I placed above is all from the Google Cloud log.